# How do I get image filenames to show in the product edit images tab?

Tags: adminhtml

I want to be able to see what image filenames are when I edit products in admin.

Something like this is what I want although the text can go anywhere, e.g. below the images, as a title tag on the images, whatever.

[image]

I have tried looking for the template page for the images tab of the admin product view page to hopefully be able to just add on the filename either as a title tag on the image or beneath the text label box. However I have got stuck.

Any ideas?

Comment: then it's simple you have to override the grid
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/show-product-thumbnail-in-grids/

follow the link and change thumnail to image

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the template `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml`. Well, don't actually edit that one. [Create a new admin theme](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/admin/using_custom_admin_theme_templates) and clone that file in your new theme.

There is some piece of html that acts as a template for all the images. It's the `tr` element that starts with

```
<tr id="<?php echo $_block->getHtmlId() ?>_template" class="template no-display">
```

Inside that `tr` element you will find a `td` like this:

```
<td class="cell-label"><input type="text" <?php if($_block->getElement()->getReadonly()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif;?> class="input-text" onkeyup="<?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?>.updateImage('__file__')" onchange="<?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?>.updateImage('__file__')" /></td>
```

all you need to do is change it to this

```
<td class="cell-label">__file__ <br /><input type="text" <?php if($_block->getElement()->getReadonly()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif;?> class="input-text" onkeyup="<?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?>.updateImage('__file__')" onchange="<?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?>.updateImage('__file__')" /></td>
```